# javax.faces.FacesException: Error decode resource data while loading JSF page

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, richfaces

I am getting the below mentioned error while loading the JSF page.
The page gets loaded successfully and the desired operation on the page is also done but this error comes.

The jsf page contains tab panels and on click of each tab panel the error comes.
Also I found that if I keep a certain portion of my page as rendered=false then the error does not come but the portion is again not rerendered.

I am using JSF2.0 with JSPs. and RF3.3

```
ERROR [[Faces Servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.faces.FacesException: Error decode resource data
at org.ajax4jsf.resource.ResourceBuilderImpl.decrypt(ResourceBuilderImpl.java:627)
at org.ajax4jsf.resource.ResourceBuilderImpl.getResourceDataForKey(ResourceBuilderImpl.java:371)
at org.ajax4jsf.resource.InternetResourceService.serviceResource(InternetResourceService.java:156)
at org.ajax4jsf.resource.InternetResourceService.serviceResource(InternetResourceService.java:141)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:508)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect data check
at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:238)
at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:256)
at org.ajax4jsf.resource.ResourceBuilderImpl.decrypt(ResourceBuilderImpl.java:621)
    ... 25 more
```

Code snippet of jsf page and component which when rendered=false in bean does not throws the above mentioned error.

```
<rich:tab ignoreDupResponses="true" id="tabModify"
    style="overflow:auto" styleClass="richTab" label="#{}"
    eventsQueue="queueForTab" actionListener="#{}">
    <rich:layout>
        <rich:layoutPanel position="right" id="pnlmodfy">
            <h:form id="frmModify">
                <h:panelGrid>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{} * :" escape="false" styleClass="intro" />
                    <h:outputText value=" : " styleClass="intro" />
                    <rich:comboBox id="Mdfy" value="#{Bean.str}"
                        suggestionValues="#{Bean.arraylist}">
                        <a4j:support id="id"
                            actionListener="#{Bean.actionListener}"
                            ajaxSingle="true" event="onchange" reRender="modify">
                        </a4j:support>
                    </rich:comboBox>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <a4j:outputPanel id="modify" ajaxRendered="true">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="modify">
                        <h:outputText value="Description *" styleClass="intro"/>
                        <h:outputText value=" : " styleClass="intro" />
                        <h:inputTextarea id="Desc" required="true"
                            styleClass="textBox" label="Description"
                            value="#{Bean.strDesc}">
                        </h:inputTextarea>
```

If outputPanel is bind to backing bean for rendering and intially the value is set to false the error does not come.
However on rerendering the outputPanel, the outputPanel never appears.

The problem basically is appearing on including  component.
I have 4 tabs in the page. On two tabs I am using the listshuttle(2 components on each tab).
On both the tabs the arraylist of source and target binded to listshuttle are same.

Is it due to this that I am binding the same list to both the shuttles.However the same code in another tab works absolutely fine....

ListShuttle code:-

```
<h:outputText value="Select" styleClass="intro" rendered="#{!empty Bean.lstAvailable}"/>
<h:outputText value=" : " styleClass="intro" />
<rich:listShuttle id="listShuttleN" sourceValue="#{Bean.lstAvailable}" targetValue="#{KPIManagement.lstSelected}"  var="items" listsHeight="100" sourceListWidth="100" targetListWidth="100" sourceCaptionLabel="Available" targetCaptionLabel="Selected" rendered="#{!empty Bean.lstAvailable}">       
<rich:column>
<h:outputLabel value="#{items}"></h:outputLabel>
</rich:column>
</rich:listShuttle>
```

ArrayList code:-

```
ArrayList<String> lstAvailable=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Inside some function

```
lstAvailable=class.function(Some variable))
this.setLstAvailable(lstAvailable);
```

---

The possible answer for this post as observed is that I am facing some kind of browser issues..

When same application is accessed from another machine there is absolutely no exception...
This is strange as I am using Firefox 11.0 and another machine has Firefox 4.0

Can this really be an issue with the browser.??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is now occuring very prominently on all Firefox upgrades>10.0..
There is some change in the Firefox browser script which does not allow the tree to be read properly.

Please add the following in your project to eliminate all Firefox browser related problems:-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

public class RichFacesFirefox11Filter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request) {
            @Override
            public String getRequestURI() {
                try {
                    return URLDecoder.decode(super.getRequestURI(), "UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot decode request URI.", e);
                }
            }
        }, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // do nothing
    }

}
```

And please make the entry of this filter in your web.xml file also.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>RichFacesFirefox11Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>Packagename.RichFacesFirefox11Filter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RichFacesFirefox11Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/a4j/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

This will surely eliminate all your problems related to Firefox Browsers and RichFaces components.

Comment: Here is the relevant JIRA issue from jboss: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12062

Comment: Also I'd suggest doing a check for FF version in the filter (can't paste the code in a sensible form in the comment, but it's as simple as matching a "Firefox/(\\d+)\\.\\d+" regex).

Comment: The problem seems to be that characters like '!' are converted by firefox to '%21', the filter proposed in this solution will convert the %21 back to '!' so resource can be found in the server. Also make note that url-pattern might need to be changed if your base url contains subpaths like <url-pattern>spring/a4j/*</url-pattern> for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I have no doubt AnglesAndDemons answer is correct here, but for some reason I could not get it to work. I'm using Richfaces 3.3.3 Final, and what did work, was downloading the patched richfaces-impl.jar from the JIRA issue https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12062

Answer (score 0):

First, the [`<rich:tabPanel>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_tabPanel.html) that wraps every `<rich:tab>` must be inside a `form` (check the note in the documentation), so the form inside the tab is not neccesary. Also, if you want to call a server action when you click in some tab, you should check that `switchType` with `server` value.

One more thing, maybe your XHTML code inside the `<a4j:outputPanel>` contains errors, it would be better if you update your post with full or more of that code.

Comment: I need to include from inside the tab.I don't think form is causing any kind of problem. For <a4j:outputPanel>, even on removing this, the error still comes. Please read my edit as I think the problem is with the listshuttle. IF listshuttle is rendered false on page load, the exception does not come. As soon as list shuttle is rendered the exception comes.