# ZipException: invalid distance too far back error when running app

Tags: java, gwt, resteasy

I have a GWT application which uses Resteasy as backend api/service, the project works properly, but when I moved the project to a different machine and run it I get this error when doing a GWT run:

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:193)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(JarInputStream.java:207)
    at org.scannotation.archiveiterator.InputStreamWrapper.read(InputStreamWrapper.java:36)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:731)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:108)
    at org.scannotation.AnnotationDB.scanClass(AnnotationDB.java:343)
    at org.scannotation.AnnotationDB.scanArchives(AnnotationDB.java:326)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap.createDeployment(ConfigurationBootstrap.java:163)
    ... 24 more
```

What could be the problem?

- Is the the GWT jars or Resteasy? What does ZipException mean? Does it mean corrupted dependency?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno Java8

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno I also tried using Java7

Comment: What exact version? 1.7_XX

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am going to go out on a limb here and say you have a class compatibility error or corrupted Jars (look at the call stack, it's trying to load classes from jar files).

Verify that you have the exact same Java version on both systems and then COPY the entire project from the working host to the non-working host. You may have a corrupted Jar.

Basically **ensure everything is identical and try again**

Comment: Where possible, use SHA256 hash to verify

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes your firewall breaks the ftp connection, so try to keep an exception for java 7 on the firewall you are using. In **Windows 7** it is:

```
netsh advfirewall set global statefulftp disable
```

Do it by running command prompt as an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Basically my project is hosted in Bitbucket. So what I did is create a folder that will serve as the new workspace folder. Then, `git clone` the project there. Then issue mvn clean install and mvn gwt:run then everything works fine.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me. Definitely sounded like you got a bad jar in a dependency sweep.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your problem is the same but, I've faced the same error and find out that it was related with Firefox version > 10.0. For some reason, Firefox converts any "!" character into something like "%21".

In my cenario, my application was triggering this error while rendering a image due to this fact. The same was NOT happening on Chrome.

That situation can be handled by implementing a Filter to treat the request.

If this case matchs your problem, take a look on this post:
[javax.faces.FacesException: Error decode resource data while loading JSF page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173128/javax-faces-facesexception-error-decode-resource-data-while-loading-jsf-page)