# java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back

Tags: apache-spark, spring-boot, zip

I am new to spring boot. I have developed an app which uses an external jar file containing an apache's spark application. My app runs without any error when I run in my local computer. However, when creating a fat jar file and intending to run it in a server, I have faced many issues.

This external jar file is quite big (160K KB). From my searches and the stackoverflow, I have figured out that there are some binding files (e.g. logging, SAXParser, security etc.) from both spring boot and spark resulting in conflicts hindering to run the jar file in a different environment.

To remedy, I have manually open the external jar file through 7-zip and deleted the binding files, such as `javax/security` and `org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class` etc. As a result, now I can start my code in another server.

First of all, does this approach make sense? If not, what should be the way?

In my code, when I run the part related to the external jar file, I get the following error. From the similar posts in stackoverflow, the jar files can be corrupted. However, I did not get how to remedy this issue.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

```
2017-04-14 18:22:10.222 ERROR 17324 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dis
patcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in contex
t with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is jav
a.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause

java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipIn
flaterInputStream.java:52) ~[mlee.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0
_121]
        at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:435) ~[na:1.
8.0_121]
        at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at scala.util.PropertiesTrait$$anonfun$scalaProps$1.apply$mcV$sp(Propert
ies.scala:37) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.util.PropertiesTrait$class.quietlyDispose(Properties.scala:43)
~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.util.PropertiesTrait$class.scalaProps(Properties.scala:37) ~[co
sinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.util.Properties$.scalaProps$lzycompute(Properties.scala:16) ~[c
osinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.util.Properties$.scalaProps(Properties.scala:16) ~[cosinelsh-1.
0.jar:na]
        at scala.util.PropertiesTrait$class.scalaPropOrNone(Properties.scala:65)
 ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.util.Properties$.scalaPropOrNone(Properties.scala:16) ~[cosinel
sh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.util.PropertiesTrait$class.$init$(Properties.scala:77) ~[cosine
lsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.util.Properties$.<init>(Properties.scala:16) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.ja
r:na]
        at scala.util.Properties$.<clinit>(Properties.scala) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar
:na]
        at scala.compat.Platform$.<init>(Platform.scala:112) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar
:na]
        at scala.compat.Platform$.<clinit>(Platform.scala) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:n
a]
        at scala.Array$.copy(Array.scala:105) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.updated0(HashMap.scala
:335) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap.$plus(HashMap.scala:57) ~[cosinels
h-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap.$plus(HashMap.scala:36) ~[cosinels
h-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:28) ~[c
osinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:24) ~[c
osinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Grow
able.scala:48) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Grow
able.scala:48) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimize
d.scala:33) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:
48) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:24
) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.$plus$plus(TraversableLike.sca
la:157) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.$plus$plus(Traversable.scala:105
) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap.$plus(HashMap.scala:60) ~[cosinels
h-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4.updated(Map.scala:172) ~[cosinels
h-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4.$plus(Map.scala:173) ~[cosinelsh-
1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4.$plus(Map.scala:158) ~[cosinelsh-
1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:28) ~[c
osinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:24) ~[c
osinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Grow
able.scala:48) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Grow
able.scala:48) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.
scala:59) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47) ~[
cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:
48) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:24
) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.generic.GenMapFactory.apply(GenMapFactory.scala:47)
~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at scala.sys.package$.env(package.scala:61) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.<init>(Utils.scala:855) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.
jar:na]
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.<clinit>(Utils.scala) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.ja
r:na]
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:58) ~[cosinelsh-1.0
.jar:na]
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:52) ~[cosinelsh-1.0
.jar:na]
        at com.soundcloud.lsh.Main5$.SpringLsh(Main5.scala:29) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.j
ar:na]
        at com.soundcloud.lsh.Main5.SpringLsh(Main5.scala) ~[cosinelsh-1.0.jar:n
a]
        at softuniBlog.controller.ReferencesController.refFormProcess(References
Controller.java:88) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.
0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvok
e(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEAS
E]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeF
orRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.
6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocabl
eHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-
webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingH
andlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[sprin
g-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingH
andlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-web
mvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapt
er.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.ja
r!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Dispatch
erServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Dispatche
rServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Frame
workServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServ
let.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat
-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkSer
vlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat
-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52
) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInter
ceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RE
LEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInter
ceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.R
ELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.do
Filter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.
jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFi
lter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/
:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticati
onFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-
4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwar
eRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spri
ng-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter
.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.j
ar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticatio
nProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[sp
ring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.d
oFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.R
ELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(Csr
fFilter.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterIn
ternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2
.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFi
lter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4
.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManage
rIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[
spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(Fi
lterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE
]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChai
nProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(D
elegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(Delegat
ingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(
RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInter
nal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RE
LEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInterna
l(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE
]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterIntern
al(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELE
ASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java
:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLig
ht.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(Abstract
Protocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpo
int.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBas
e.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskTh
read.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That error means that your data was corrupted in transit somehow.

Answer (score 0):

### Some recommendations:

1. Actually if you have duplicate version of jars or any jar conflict, you must have to correct by removing another jar.
2. Verify that you have the exact same Java version on both your local and server systems.
3. You may have a corrupted Jar. Rebuild it after resolving conflict.
4. Ensure that everything is identical and try again

Resource Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596749/2293534