# Spring boot crashes after few hours with the exception "java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back"

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a standalone spring boot (1.5.1) application using castor 1.2, spring integration, kafka publishers, and couchbase functionalities. After running for few hours in Linux (java version "1.8.0_191") the app starts getting the below error -

```
Failed to load configuration from classpath: /org/castor/core/castor.core.properties
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
        at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:435)
        at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
        at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
        at org.castor.core.util.Configuration.loadFromClassPath(Configuration.java:187)
        at org.castor.core.util.Configuration.loadDefaultProperties(Configuration.java:136)
```

This is not happening during the start up, the app starts fine keeps on running for few hours and then suddenly the error pops up and never recovers. We need to manually restart the process.
Can you please suggest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ZipException: invalid distance too far back error when running app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594307/zipexception-invalid-distance-too-far-back-error-when-running-app)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back while decompressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151669/java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-distance-too-far-back-while-decompressing)

Comment: This is not happening during the start up, the app starts fine keeps on running for few hours and then suddenly the error pops up and never recovers. We need to then manually restart the process. Please suggest

Comment: Is `castor.core.properties` ever read successfully, or is the failure occurring on the first attempt to read the file? If it's the latter, I would guess that you have a corrupted jar file.